# Github Action no permission to write file

Tags: python, github-actions

On Github action, running `python -m unittest discover`. One of the unit tests writes a file, and the following error shows.

```
    with open(self.file_path, 'w') as f:
```

> PermissionError: [Errno 13] Permission denied: '/home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/data_test/ABCD.json'

I tried to do a chmod before running the unit tests, and then the same problem shows up.

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /home/runner/work/my_api/my_api/data_test
```

Comment: Do chmod without sudo

Comment: @eshirvana Same problem without sudo!

Comment: Did you try using `w+`? You may want to try running the script with `sudo` too.

Comment: @bekirbakar `sudo python script.py` solves the issue